# gnuradio-companion.py under WIndows 8.1 just flashes the Python screen

Tags: python, windows, gnuradio

I just installed gnuradio-companion (for about the 10th time).
When I try to run it by clicking on gnuradio-companion.py in the bin folder all I get is a python screen with a blast of text that closes before I can see what it says.  When I first tried it I got the errors about the paths not being right.  I corrected them and now I just get this flash.  Is there some way to keep the screen open so I can see the errors?

Background: I said this was (about) my 10th attempt.  After many failures I got to the point that I had version 3.6.?.? running except it didn't have the source I needed (rtl-sdr).  I found that if I installed version 3.7.?.? I could get some of the source components from 3.7 and copy them to the 3.6 folder but there were some osmosdr files I couldn't find.  I decided that by now, after all these attempts, maybe I should uninstall everything associated with gnuradio and do a clean install using v3.7.13.4/v1.5 from http://www.gcndevelopment.com/gnuradio/downloads.htm

I assumed at that point that all I had to do was click on gnuradio-companion.py in the bin folder.  Well, I had to make the python that came with this download the default for .py file types.  Then I had to get the paths right (as I said above).  Now I am stuck at the flashing screen.  Did I miss something else in this install process?

Comment: Don't try running 3.6.X; it's so obsolete, you won't be doing anything useful with it. And the whole point of versioning is that files from 3.7 aren't compatible with files from 3.6, and you have probably broken your installations by copying files around.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting input() at the end of the code to have it wait for user input before it finishes executing and closes

Comment: Do you mean at the last line of gnuradio-companion.py?  I really don't know anything about Python but I tried it anyway.  It didn't help, the screen still flashes and goes away.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure about that then